# Is it possible to use TabView Navigation within SideDrawer Navigation

Tags: nativescript

I need to implement layout like in Twitter app, where the app has TabView for primary information and SideDrawer for supplementary information.

If I try to init RadSideDrawer mainContent with TabView and Frame I got empty screen:

```
...
<nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
    <TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">
        <TabViewItem class="tab-view-item" title="catalog">
            <Frame defaultPage="pages/catalog/catalog-page"></Frame>
        </TabViewItem>
    </TabView>
</nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
...
```

But if I init RadSideDrawer mainContent with Frame I got correct page:

```
...
<nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
     <Frame defaultPage="pages/catalog/catalog-page"></Frame>
</nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
...
```

What it the correct way to combine TabView Navigation and SideDrawer Navigation?

Comment: I just create [the playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=A5JeYp&v=2) with this issue. In file `app-root.xml` I put different code variant (switch by comment) in `nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the `Frame` should be wrapped within `TabViewItem.view` and `TabViewItem` must be wrapped by `<TabView.items>`

```
<nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
    <TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">
        <TabView.items>
          <TabViewItem class="tab-view-item" title="catalog">
            <TabViewItem.view>
             <Frame defaultPage="pages/catalog/catalog-page"></Frame>
            </TabViewItem.view>
          </TabViewItem>
        </TabView.items>
    </TabView>
</nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help ☹️

Comment: Can you share the Playground Sample?

Comment: Yes, I just created one - [SideDrawer playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=A5JeYp&v=3). TabView does not work for sure under iOS.

Comment: Just noticed in action, you seem missing `<TabView.items>` too.

Comment: Wow! Adding `<TabView.items>` and `<TabViewItem.view>`  fix my issue - [updated SideDrawer playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=A5JeYp&v=4). Manoj thank you a lot!
But why `TabView` works without these nodes when I use it alone?